# Parameter selection for update

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I am trying to convert one of our most simple reports to Reporting Services.

The original excel report calls several stored procedures using the results of one to structure the next as it drills down through the data.

I currently have 2 datasets both of which call stored procedures.

The first is called `GetGlobalCustomers`. This populates a resultset which returns the connection info for each database (we have split our database per customer) and returns the fields `ID`, `Name`, `Customer` and `Server`.

The second is called `GetSchedules` which needs the Server and Name provided by `GetGlobalCustomers` to query the correct database.

However I only want to select the Customer by name, not the individual server/name (remembering which customer is on which server and what their database name is nigh impossible).

So I have a parameter called `CustomerName`, pushed to the top of the parameters list which presents the user the Customer to select first with the value being the `ID`. I also have two parameters called `DBServer` and `DBName`. How do I set `DBServer` and `DBName` to be dependent on the Customer selected? There doesn't appear to be a readily apparent means.

I am guessing that it needs to be part of Available Values and Specify Values but I can't figure out how to say "For this customer `ID` use this database/Name". I think I could by creating two extra datasets which perform a select by id queries for `dbserver`/`dbname`, but if I need to do that each time I want to select by parameter I will have dozens of datasets.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that though your datasource with one caveat: you cannot use shared data sources.

The data source connection string can contain parameters in this case. For example:

="Data Source="+ Parameters!P_Environment.Value + ";Initial Catalog=MyDB;"

You are correct in saying that it needs to be part of available values. One possibility is to make the customer reference the full connection string which would be passed to the datasource. So in this case you would have one parameter which presents the customer name as the parameter text and the connection string as value.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me (or I didn't explain myself well enough). I have a database that has the global information in it. This has a list of all the databases and their locations in it. This is accessed via GetGlobalCustomers to retrieve the Server/Name to use in subsequent queries. As far as I can tell I don't need to change data source as the actual Store Procedure uses the parameters to locate the correct database.

Currently I am passing the ID of the database and using a select from the master table for the Name/Server pair which is horribly inefficient.